# Remove linked application from google game services in developer console

Tags: google-play-games

I have an android game that uses Google Game Services for leader boards and achievements. I have created linked applications with my debug key to be able to test the application, but recently i had to re install my computer and i got a new debug key. To be able to test i added the new debug key as a new linked application. But i cant find a way to delete the old linked application with the old debug key. I have tried deleting the the credentials from the API console first and to unpublish the game services the but still cant delete the old linked application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just found this piece of info :( :

**Once a game services project has been published, the linked app(s) cannot be removed without deleting the entire project.**

**Here's how to delete a project:**

Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.

Click Game Services.

Select the project.

At the bottom of the Game Details page, click the link to go to the API Console Project.

Example: This game is linked to the API console project called 'PROJECT_NAME'

In the API Console Project, on the left menu, click APIs & auth > Credentials.

Under "Client ID for Android application", click Delete.

On the left menu, click Projects.

Click Billing & settings.

Click Delete project.

To confirm that your project has been deleted, go back to your Google Play Developer Console and click Games services Game Services.

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/6097563?hl=en&ref_topic=15868#ts=6097687,6097659

Answer (score 5):

I just solved a similar problem with Google Game Services. The solution is to not link another application, but rather to just change the SHA-1 fingerprint.

Note your OAuth2 Client ID for the linked app on Google Play Developer Console (https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)

Head over to your Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com/). In Credentials under APIs & auth select your OAuth2 Client ID that you noted before. Change the SHA-1 to the new one from your new keystore. Hit save and you should be ready to go.