# Unity3D - Solve wrong Play Game Service configuration (keystore change impacts)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, android-keystore

we've made a game for Android using Unity3D and published on Play Store as **alpha release** (and it's still in alpha!). We've also configured the Play Game Sarvices in order to define leaderboard and achievements and linked this configuration to the app via its SHA-1 certificate (that, if I understand correctly, derives from the keystore used to build and sign the apk via Unity).

Unfortunately **the Play Game Services configuration has been published with some errors** (now we know we could have left it unpublished just to test it...) that cannot be undone (i.e. achievement incremental instead of standard). Now we need to create a new Play Game Services configuration but we are not able to link it to the same app 'cause it's already linked (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094031/remove-linked-application-from-google-game-services-in-developer-console), but not clear). So, how can we proceed to clean the mess?

- We cannot change keystore, the Play Store won't publish app with same package with different signature
- We cannot get rid of the wrong Play Game Services configuration because has been published

The only solution that I can think of is to unpublish current app, build a new apk with different package name and different keystore, then re-publish it on Play Store and build for it a new Play Game Services configuration from scratch. The old app with the old package name and keystore will remain unpublished: no user except us has used it and no one will ever know about it; we'll keep it on our developer console until the end of time though.

Am i right? Hope not.

Thank you all,
Dolfiz

Comment: You should be able to publish a new Play Game Services configuration without the errors.

Comment: Of course I can do it, but I cannot connect it to the same app as before, Google Play refuses it. From what I've seen you can have multiple apps linked to the same Play Game Services configuration, but not vice-versa: you cannot link two different Play Game Services configuration to the same app.

Comment: Why cant you change whatever let you connect it to the app and publish again...

Comment: @Nanoc 1) we cannot fix the existing Play Game Services configuration because it has been published (and some fields are not editable after first publishing); 2) we cannot create a new Play Game Services configuration for the same game because Google refuses to link another configuration to the same app (it recognizes the SHA-1 sign); 3) we cannot publish same app with new signature (not allowed if it's the same package name)