# Google Sign-In not working on published app

Tags: java, android, firebase, oauth, google-signin

- [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10) didn't solve my problem
- [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store) didn't solve my problem
- [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304414/google-sign-in-service-not-working-after-publish-on-playstore?rq=1) didn't make any sense to me but doesn't seem to fix my problem anyway.

So, I've release my app on the PlayStore and the google sign in doesn't work.
I've tried to run my app with the debug and release sha1, and that got me an ApiException: 12500:

After like 2 hours of research I figured I had to use the Google Play Signin SHA-1. I did, now I get an ApiException: 10:, at least that's some progress.

But there I am stuck.
As my knowledge goes, the ApiException 10 is either a SHA or client Id problem.
It can't be a SHA problem since I now use Play's SHA (In the firebase console I have the release and play sha-1 and updated services.json, adding the debug sha just brings me back to apiexception 12500).

So I thought and still think the problem is my client Id BUT
Using the `default_web_client_id` doesn't work. Both client ID's for both SHA's extracted from google-services don't work. The client Id I created in Google Developers Console won't work.

So I'm begging you to help me understand what I'm missing.
Thanks.

Comment: google play uses their own sign key to uploaded apk, you need to get SHA1 key of your google sign key

Comment: That's what I did, after getting Google Play's SHA1 I get an ApiException 10

Comment: I'm not marking this question again as a duplicate despite the fact that it is. It's the same exact problem as in those three linked answres. You get an `ApiException 10` when you have an incorrect `debug key`, `release key` or a `Google Play App signing key`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the answers don't help my case, so my problem must be diffrent somehow, and thank you , btw.

Answer (score 1):

### What I tried first :

I want through this error ApiException: 12500 for a long time. I tried everthing :

- remove my debugkeystore, recreate one
- add support email on firebase console
- change versions of plugin
- update google on my device

But when I was browsing stackoverflow, I found a solution :

### Maybe the solution :

I went to this page (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)
Do not forget to select your project on the list (top left). Then go on "Oauth consent screen"

I filled almost all the fields : the application logo, the email support, the application homepage link, application privacy policy link (with the project.firebaseapp.com); and I saved.

[image]

Now it's working, I can login.

Hope this will help

### Source

Thanks to answer of Pranjal Gupta : [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

Comment: @BetaReogen I have not mentionned in my answer but don't forget to fill the support email in this page too.

Comment: Yeah, I only had set up the support mail, app name and logo

Comment: Hey, I filled that in, what keys did you have in the google-services.json? debug, release and/or google play's sha-1?

Comment: debug, I have done something like that : keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: Yeah my problem is happening in the published app :(